# Is there a property named "rowgroup" like "colgroup" in XHTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

The following `w3c` documents mentions `rowgroup`

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#rowgroups

> `<!ENTITY % Scope "(row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)">`

Is there such an attribute or property?

Comment: they probably should have called the tbody tag 'rowgroup' instead. 'body' kind of suggest that there can be only one, but you can have multiple tbody nodes within the same table, no problem. tbody groups together rows. Why it's not called 'rowgroup'? because the "spec people" are not perfect, I'd say.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no such element. If you want to group rows, you can put the particular `tr` elements in the same class.

---

The “rowgroup” you are referring to is a row group that is naturally formed by an element like `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot`. And [*Scope*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#Scope) is used to define the value set in the same-named [attribute `scope`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#adef-scope) that is used to refer to the scope the current `th` element is providing information for:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->
>
> <!-- Scope is simpler than headers attribute for common tables -->
> <!ENTITY % Scope "(row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)">
>
> <!-- TH is for headers, TD for data, but for cells acting as both use TD -->
> <!ATTLIST (TH|TD)                      -- header or data cell --
>   %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
>   abbr        %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- abbreviation for header cell --
>   axis        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- comma-separated list of related headers--
>   headers     IDREFS         #IMPLIED  -- list of id's for header cells --
>   scope       %Scope;        #IMPLIED  -- scope covered by header cells --
>   rowspan     NUMBER         1         -- number of rows spanned by cell --
>   colspan     NUMBER         1         -- number of cols spanned by cell --
>   %cellhalign;                         -- horizontal alignment in cells --
>   %cellvalign;                         -- vertical alignment in cells --
>   >
> ```

Here *Scope* is a [parameter entity](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-6.htm#PARAM) with the value `(row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)`. This entity is then refered to in the declaration of the attribute value list of `scope` with the [parameter entity reference](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-6.htm#param-ent) `%Scope;`.

Parameter entities in SGML are like variables and references to such parameter entities are replaced by its values. That means the following two attribute definitions are equal:

```
<!ENTITY % Scope "(row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)">
<!ATTLIST (FOOBAR)
  scope       %Scope;        #IMPLIED
>

<!ATTLIST (FOOBAR)
  scope       (row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)        #IMPLIED
>
```

Comment: but see my comments in @naivists answer

Comment: @jitendra: You’re just misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 13):

> Table rows may be grouped into a table head, table foot, and one or
>   more table body sections, using the THEAD, TFOOT and TBODY elements,
>   respectively. This division enables user agents to support scrolling
>   of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long
>   tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be
>   repeated on each page that contains table data.
>
> The table head and table foot should contain information about the
>   table's columns. The table body should contain rows of table data.
>
> When present, each THEAD, TFOOT, and TBODY contains a row group. Each
>   row group must contain at least one row, defined by the TR element.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: Important to stress the point: a table can have **multiple `tbody` elements**.  Use them for grouping.  Also see the 'scope' attribute for `td` and `th` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th#attr-scope

Answer (score 4):

There is no such element, however I think that `TBODY` does what you need - contains all the relevant data rows in your table. So, you can create your styles using CSS statements like `TBODY TD {color:red}`

Comment: here is mentioned rowgroup `<!ENTITY % Scope "(row|col|rowgroup|colgroup)">` http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6 . but no detailed info

Answer (score 2):

[W3C Spec on the `th` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) shows an example of using scope and multiple rowgroups - i.e. multiple `tbody` elements.

Note: The `tbody` elements in this example identify the range of the row groups.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> ID
            <th> Measurement
            <th> Average
            <th> Maximum
    <**tbody**>
        <tr> <td> <th **scope**=rowgroup> Cats <td> <td>
        <tr> <td> 93 <th **scope**=row> Legs <td> 3.5 <td> 4
        <tr> <td> 10 <th **scope**=row> Tails <td> 1 <td> 1
    </**tbody**>
    <**tbody**>
        <tr> <td> <th **scope**=rowgroup> English speakers <td> <td>
        <tr> <td> 32 <th **scope**=row> Legs <td> 2.67 <td> 4
        <tr> <td> 35 <th **scope**=row> Tails <td> 0.33 <td> 1
    </**tbody**>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried to edit and format your code, yet it still doesn't make sense. You are missing a bunch of quotes and closing tags.

Comment: the only answer which properly explains what that weird 'scope' thing is about. Look at the code here and the rendered HTML, you'll understand it right away. What the other answers say about 'scope', I don't find very intelligible.

Answer (score 1):

The [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#rowgroups) that you posted in your question answers the question for you. Row groups are defined by the `thead`, `tfoot` and `tbody` elements. In the other part you mention, `rowgroup` is simply a *value* for the `scope` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can group sections of rows in a `table` using

- `thead` to represent the block of rows that consist of the column labels (headers)
- `tbody` to represent a block of rows that consist of a body of data
- `tfoot` to represent the block of rows that consist of the column summaries (footers)