# How do I highlight two table rows where one row has a cell with a "rowspan" property?

Tags: html, css

This is how the table looks like:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is that when the user hovers over one of the rows, the other adjacent row gets highlighted as well as the row over which the user hovered. I tried this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background: #CCC;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd):hover + tr {
  background: #CCC;
}

table tr:nth-child(even):hover {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
    <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This almost works, but when you hover over a row that reads "The row 2 text goes here", only that row gets highlighted. Is there an HTML/CSS only workaround for this issue?

What I am thinking of is something like [`<rowgroup>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490584/is-there-a-property-named-rowgroup-like-colgroup-in-xhtml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tbody` tag is a group, and you can use it [multiple times](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Multiple_bodies):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody:hover {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
      <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
      <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Text here</td>
      <td>The row 1 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The row 2 text goes here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```